# How parse/browse history with Jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, browser-history

On Windows 8 App, `history.back()` and `history.forward()` can't perform, so I want to recover all history on an Array to use `$.mobile.changePage();`

But "How parse/browse history ?"

Ideas ?

Thx.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/balupton/History.js/ this might help you consolidate to using `History.pushState` which has `History.forward` and `History.back`

Comment: You can't really for security reasons.  Otherwise every site you visit could access what pages you have visited which would be a breach of privacy for most people.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a client side javascript array and add a new entry each time the page load event fires in the jQuery mobile api?

```
var myPageHistory = [];
$(document).bind('pageload', function( event, data ){
myPageHistory.push(data.url); // add the page to the history array
})
```